# How to run this program repeatedly?

Tags: c#

The program runs perfectly for a single attempt, thought I would like to add another feature that will let the user to chose either quite or continue the game repeatedly.

The issue I am having is that it runs the program and then this line of code Console.WriteLine("Go again? Y/N"); runs right after asking the user "Enter your guess: ". 
Is there any way to fix this issue so the program runs to the end for as many times as wished for?
I tried with a wider while loop too, but it didn't help.

using System;

```
namespace HiLoGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool correct = false;
            bool repeat = true;
            int guess = 0;
            int totalGuess = 0;

            Random random = new Random();
            int returnNum = random.Next(1, 100);

            Console.WriteLine("*** Welcome to the Hi-Lo game ***");
            Console.WriteLine("The computer chose a number between 1 and 100, you guess it");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
                guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guess < returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess > returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess == returnNum)
                {
                    correct = true;
                    totalGuess++;
                    Console.WriteLine("*** YOU GOT IT! ***");
                    Console.WriteLine("Total try: {0}", totalGuess);
                }
            } while (!correct);



            Console.WriteLine("Go again? Y/N");
            string go = Console.ReadLine();
            if (go == "Y" || go == "y")
            {
                repeat = true;
            }
            else
            {
                repeat = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another do/while loop is your friend :-)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same as you did for your gameLoop.
Short example:

```
do
{
    GameLoop();

    Console.WriteLine("Go again? Y/N");
    go = Console.ReadLine();
} while (go == "Y" || go == "y");
```

Full example:

```
using System;

namespace HiLoGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string go = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("*** Welcome to the Hi-Lo game ***");
            Console.WriteLine("The computer chose a number between 1 and 100, you guess it");
            do
            {
                GameLoop();

                Console.WriteLine("Go again? Y/N");
                go = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (go == "Y" || go == "y");

        }

        private static void GameLoop()
        {
            bool correct = false;
            bool repeat = true;
            int guess = 0;
            int totalGuess = 0;

            Random random = new Random();
            int returnNum = random.Next(1, 100);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
                guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guess < returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess > returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess == returnNum)
                {
                    correct = true;
                    totalGuess++;
                    Console.WriteLine("*** YOU GOT IT! ***");
                    Console.WriteLine("Total try: {0}", totalGuess);
                }
            } while (!correct);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. It definitely helped :)

Comment: @user9419320 If this answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool repeat = true;
            while (repeat)
            {
                DoTheGame();
                Console.WriteLine("Go again? Y/N");
                string go = Console.ReadLine();
                if (go == "Y" || go == "y")
                {
                    repeat = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    repeat = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DoTheGame()
        {
            bool correct = false;

            int guess = 0;
            int totalGuess = 0;

            Random random = new Random();
            int returnNum = random.Next(1, 100);

            Console.WriteLine("*** Welcome to the Hi-Lo game ***");
            Console.WriteLine("The computer chose a number between 1 and 100, you guess it");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
                guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guess < returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess > returnNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high!");
                    totalGuess++;
                }

                else if (guess == returnNum)
                {
                    correct = true;
                    totalGuess++;
                    Console.WriteLine("*** YOU GOT IT! ***");
                    Console.WriteLine("Total try: {0}", totalGuess);
                }
            } while (!correct);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this suggestion too, but what #Che has suggested above did the job beautifully.